# How can I access my vectors indices when I am assigning values?

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing, indices

I am trying to code something in Matlab and it involves a lot of accessing elements in vectors. Below is a snippet of code that I am working on:

```
x(1)=1;

for i=2:18
    x(i)=0;
end

for i=1:18
    y(i)=1;
end

for i = 0:262124
    x(i+18+1) = x(i+7+1) + mod(x(i+1),2); 
    y(i+18+1) = y(i+10+1) + y(i+7+1) + y(i+5+1) + mod(y(i+1), 2);  
end

% n can be = 0, 1, 2,..., 262142
n = 2;

for i = 0: 262142
   z(i+1) = x(mod(i+n+1, 262143)); %error: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.    
end
```

In the last "for" loop where I am initialising vector z(), I get an error saying: "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals." However, when I do not suppres z(i+1) by ommiting the semi colon, the program is able to run, and I can see the values of z in the workspace. Why is this?

The code I am writing in Matlab is based upon the series of instructions shown in the image below. However, I can't seem to track down my error which leads to me not being able to access the elements of x() (without not suppressing the output of z()).

[image]

I appreciate any ideas :-) Thank you!

Comment: I'm no expert on MATLAB, but are you sure the program *finishes* when you leave out the semicolon?  For small values of *n* like the *n = 2* you have in the code, the last loop would make it most of the way through before you get to the point where you're trying to access *x(0)*.  According to the error you're supposed to have *positive* indices, and of course zero isn't positive.

Comment: Looks like this question/script would benefit from consistently considering `1` to be pseudo `0` throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code breaks at that loop last iteration because , for `i=262140` you get

```
(mod(i+n+1, 262143)) = 0
```

so you cant access `x(0)` in matlab. the first elements of any variable is `x(1)`.

In addition, and not related to your question, this code doesn't use the advantages matlab has, instead of

```
for i=2:18
    x(i)=0;
end
```

you can just write:

```
x(2:18)=0;
```

etc